# set integrable with functions multiplication

Tags: isabelle, theorem-proving

I'm trying to prove this lemma:

```
  lemma set_integral_mult:
  fixes f g :: "_ ⇒ _ :: {banach, second_countable_topology}"
  assumes "set_integrable M A (λx. f x)"  "set_integrable M A (λx. g x)"
    shows "set_integrable M A (λx. f x * g x)"
```

and

```
  lemma set_integral_mult1:
  fixes f :: "_ ⇒ _ :: {banach, second_countable_topology}"
  assumes "set_integrable M A (λx. f x)"  
    shows "set_integrable M A (λx. f x * f x)"
```

but I couldn't. I've seen that it is proved for addition and subtraction:

```
  lemma set_integral_add [simp, intro]:
  fixes f g :: "_ ⇒ _ :: {banach, second_countable_topology}"
  assumes "set_integrable M A f" "set_integrable M A g"
  shows "set_integrable M A (λx. f x + g x)"
    and "LINT x:A|M. f x + g x = (LINT x:A|M. f x) + (LINT x:A|M. g x)"
  using assms by (simp_all add: scaleR_add_right)

  lemma set_integral_diff [simp, intro]:
  assumes "set_integrable M A f" "set_integrable M A g"
  shows "set_integrable M A (λx. f x - g x)" and "LINT x:A|M. f x - g x =
    (LINT x:A|M. f x) - (LINT x:A|M. g x)"
  using assms by (simp_all add: scaleR_diff_right)
```

or even for scalar multiplication but not for two functions multiplication?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that it is quite simply not true. The function `f(x) = 1 / sqrt(x)` is integrable on the set (0;1], and the integral has the value 2. Its square `f(x)² = 1 / x` on the other hand is not integrable on the set (0;1]. The integral diverges.

Comment: Thanks Manuel, but what in case if we have this simple lemma `  lemma mult: 
  fixes f g :: "real ⇒ real"
  assumes "set_integrable M A f" "set_integrable M A g" 
   shows "(LINT x:A|M. ((f x)⇧2 + (f x * g x) + (g x)⇧2)) = (LINT x:A|M. (f x)^2) + (LINT x:A|M. (f x * g x)) +  (LINT x:A|M. (g x)^2)"` ? whithout assumption or prove like above (two function multiplication) I gess that this can't prove.

Comment: This lemma is not true either. As I said above, if `f` is integrable, `f^2` does not necessarily have to be integrable, and then some of the integrals occursing in your goal will be undefined. What are you *actually* trying to prove? I.e. what do you need this lemma for?

Comment: Actually, I need to prove Schwarz integral inequality for reals. Which is as bellow: `lemma  schwaz_ineq:
fixes M
fixes f g :: "real ⇒ real"
assumes "⋀x. x ∈ A"
"set_integrable M A f " "set_integrable M A g "
shows " (LINT x:A|M. f x * g x )  ≤  sqrt(LINT x:A|M. (f x)^2 ) * sqrt(LINT x:A|M. (g x)^2)" ` . So this comes down to the need to two functions multiplication.

Comment: You will not be able to prove anything like that because if `f^2` is not integrable on `A`, then `LINT x:A|M. (f x)^2` is undefined in Isabelle. You could probably show it for `nn_integral`, since if `f` is integrable but `f^2` isn't, that essentially means that the `f^2` is measurable, but its integral is infinite. You would then simply have to do a case distinction on whether `f^2` and `g^2` are integrable or not. Depending on your ultimate goal, it is probably easier to just assume that `f^2` and `g^2` are integrable, like some textbooks also do.

Comment: Manuel , many thanks for your explanations. Basically, I proved it by assuming that `f^2` and `g^2` are integrable but I want to reduce the number of assumptions in my main theory by just assuming that `f` and `g` are integrable. However, it seems that I can't do so. thanks again.